# Экранирование с помощью JS RegEx

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо экранировать все символы ' (скобка) методом RegEx в строке ( \' ''' ' ' ), нужно учесть то что в строке возможно уже экранированный символ.

```
var str = " \' ''' ' ' ";
str = str.replace(/([^\\])(\')/g, '$1\\$2');
\\ str === \' \''\' \' \'
```

Примере выше не подходит когда символ повторяется, заменяет через один символ.

Comment: Наверно, у вас `var str = " \\' ''' ' ' ";`. В `var str = " \' ''' ' ' ";` нет экранированной кавычки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант:

```js
var str = " \\' ''' ' ' ";

str = str.replace(/\\'|'|:P/g, '\\\'');

console.log( str );
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо!